# Remote Access to Virtual Desktops ; Remote Access

Tags: networking, virtual, desktop

I don´t know if this is the best place to ask this question.

But I need to find a solution to a problem I have.

I need to provide access to personal virtual desktops to a few users.

And I need to see what options I have for this.

I can provide some machines to work as servers if needed. And I can pay if there is some type of option using the cloud or other service.

I just need to be able to provide a few user the access to a desktop with security and with long lag and latency . So they can work and use application in the remote server.

I will be thankfull for all the help and solutions

Comment: Sorry, but you question is off-topic here (Programming questions) Try with http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with https://deskroll.com/ ?

I use it bc it doesnt require installation, works easy in the browser and has free trial and very cheap license.